# ls --color | grep doesn't work

Tags: grep, regular-expression, ls, colors

I'm trying to list all hidden dirs with the following command

```
ls -lhAF1 | grep -E '^d.*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \.'
```

which works perfectly fine

> Explanation for Regex: I'm trying to get all rows that have the following Format: d, then some text, then the timestamp, then a space, then the dot and then more text

However when I try to color the ls output with this command:

```
ls --color -lhAF1 | grep -E '^d.*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \.'
```

It gives zero results, the output without `--color` is:

> drwxr-xr-x 1 User Group    4096    Feb 1   08:48 .invisible

Why does ls / grep behave this way?

Comment: where is the difference between the two invocations of `ls ...`?

Comment: @Anthon sorry, just copy pasted and forgot to add  `--colors` in second code

Comment: I thought so, but didn't want to guess wrong and edit that in myself in case there was some commandline issue.

Comment: You may control if you call the shell built in comands or the system-wide one by giving the full path. e.g. '/usr/bin/ls -lhAF1' instead of 'ls -lhAF1'. They may behave differently

Comment: `ls` is at `/bin/ls`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`--color` adds escape sequences for the color. You can see this if you redirect the output (of `ls --color`) to a file.

This is what it looks like:

```
 drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4.0K Jan  9 08:23 ^[[01;34m.cabal^[[0m/
```

To account for this, try this instead:

```
 ls -lhAF1 --color | grep -E '^d.*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} .*\.'
```

Comment: Thanks, that as exactly the problem, but it only works for dirs that do not contain a dot, but dirs like hello.world would also be accepted, I tried it with `^d.*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \^\[\[.*\.`, which works in RegExr, but not in my shell

Comment: I came one step closer to the solution: `grep $'\x1b'` matches the ASCII Escape, but this doesn't work with double quotes around

Answer (score 6):

Parsing `ls` is [often a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Often, but [not always](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). Here's another suggestion for you, which collects the required directories together before passing the set to `ls`.

```
find .* -maxdepth 0 -type d \( -name '.[^.]' -o -name '.??*' \) -exec ls -ld --color=always {} +
```

It's been pointed out that the original code actually limits the list of directories to those modified in the last six months. This can be handled with the following alternative solution.

```
find .* -maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime -180 -mtime +0 \( -name '.[^.]' -o -name '.??*' \) -exec ls -ld --color=always {} +
```

<sub>As ever, if your `find` doesn't understand the trailing `+` replace it with `\;` at the cost of efficiency.</sub>

Comment: Presumably with his grep for HH:MM, the OP wanted only the files last modified between 6 months ago and now, for which you'd also need a `-mtime -180 -mtime +0`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah, I missed that, thank you. It would have been easier if this had been included in the description of the requirement, of course. (I like the `-mtime +0`.)

Comment: Likely it was an oversight of the OP, see the discussion on his own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `ls` always colorizes its output even if it is connected to a terminal. From `man ls`:

```
   --color[=WHEN]
          colorize the output.   WHEN  defaults  to  'always'  or  can  be
          'never' or 'auto'.  More info below
```

Many other tools such as `grep` do not retain colors when standard output is terminal but for some reasons `ls` was designed to act differently. Colorizing output is achieved by using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that are interpreted by your terminal. Redirect `ls` output to a file and open it in editor:

```
$ ls --color  -lhaF1  > /tmp/RESULT
$ less /tmp/RESULT
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  3 ja   users 4.0K Feb  2 09:47 ESC[0mESC[01;34m.ESC[0m/
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root  4.0K Feb  2 09:51 ESC[30;42m..ESC[0m/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ja   users 4.0K Feb  2 09:47 ESC[01;34m.invisibleESC[0m/
-rw-r--r--  1 ja   users    0 Feb  2 08:35 a|a
```

If you have `$LESS` variable set you probably need to unset it before running `less` in order to see raw escape codes instead of color. So, to sum up, when using `--color` what `grep` gets is not what you see but a bunch of escape codes together with it. To fix it either don't use `--colors` at all or set it to `--auto`:

```
$ ls --color=auto -lhaF1 | grep  -E '^d.*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured out how to list all hidden dirs while preserving the Colors and not including dirs like "hello.world":

```
 ls -lhAF1 --color | grep -E "^d[rwx-]{9}.*[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} "$'\x1b'"\[([0-9]{1,2}m?)(;[0-9]{1,2}m?)?\."
```

Comment: Note that rwx are not the only permissions, especially for directories where t and s are common (see /tmp for instance). Only files last modified between 6 months ago and now have their time displayed with HH:MM (in the C and most English locales at least).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas well the permissions can be included easily, but how is the timestamp displayed when they were modified more than 6 month ago?

Comment: more than 6 months ago or in the future. Check `ls -l /bin` for examples. `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   31240 Mar 14  2015 uname` in a en_GB.UTF-8 locale on a GNU system,

Answer (score 0):

Rather than applying `grep` to the output of `ls` which is not post-processable reliably anyway, I'd rather filter on the list of files passes to `ls`, like:

```
ls -lFhd --color -- .*(/)
```

In `zsh`. Or as your own approach suggests you only want the directories last modified between 6 months ago and now and not the ones with special permissions:

```
ls -lFhd --color -- .*(/mM-6mM+0f-7000)
```

Comment: if I excute this it throws the error "Syntax error near unexpected token ("
Note: I'm actually using Git Bash / Cygwin on Windows

Comment: @danielr1996, yes, that's for zsh, not bash. Check cygwin for a better Unix-like environment  for Windows (includes zsh and bash).

Comment: Oh well, you wrote that it's zsh, the Problem is that in our Company we can only use git bash and i was just playing arround. But at home I'm actually using zsh, can you tell me how the feature is called you're using

Just as a side note: isn't git bash built on cygwin?

Comment: @daniel1996, they are [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). Not sure about git-bash. I had heard it was outdated versions of some GNU utilities built for MS-Windows. It may be different now.